How to bind a http.server to a remote socks proxy?
I've a webserver that is going to answer requests at a remote socks5 proxy.
I want the webserver to connect to the proxy, send the bind command, and listen to a connection.
How can I set up a http.server to bind and listen on a remote port?
I have tried to override server_bind without success:
class TestHTTPServer ( http.server.HTTPServer ):
    def __init__ ( self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, proxy_host=None, proxy_port=None, bind_and_activate=True ):
        if ':' in (str)(server_address[0]):
            self.address_family = socket.AF_INET6
        else:
            self.address_family = socket.AF_INET
        
        self.proxy_host = proxy_host
        self.proxy_port = proxy_port
        
        super().__init__ ( server_address, RequestHandlerClass, bind_and_activate )
    
    def serve_forever ( self, poll_interval = 0.5 ):
        self.socket.settimeout ( poll_interval )
        while not stop_unittest_event.is_set ():
            try:
                self.handle_request ()
            except OSError:
                pass

    def server_bind ( self ):
        if self.proxy_host is None or self.proxy_port is None:
            super().server_bind ()
        else:
            self.socket = socks.socksocket()
            self.socket.set_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, self.server_address[0], self.server_address[1])
            self.socket.bind(self.server_address)

It seems as set_proxy only handles client requests (not servers). How can this code be changed to listen on a socks5 port?
It is something an FTP-server does in active mode.

A socket is something on the local system. You cannot create a socket in your local app which belongs on a remote system. It is unclear what problem you are actually trying to solve, but the direction you try is wrong. "It seems as set_proxy only handle client requests" - correct, the purpose of a SOCKS5 proxy is to allow clients access servers through the proxy, not the other way.

class TestHTTPServerServer ( http.server.HTTPServer ):
    def __init__ ( self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, bind_and_activate=True, **kwargs ):
        self.proxy_args = kwargs.copy ()
        
        if bool ( self.proxy_args ) is False : # standard way of initalization
            if ':' in (str)(server_address[0]):
                self.address_family = socket.AF_INET6
            else:
                self.address_family = socket.AF_INET
            
            self.allow_reuse_address = True
            
            super().__init__ ( server_address, RequestHandlerClass, bind_and_activate )
        else:
            self.proxy_args = kwargs.copy ()
            
            self.RequestHandlerClass = RequestHandlerClass
            
            self.socket = socket.socket ( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
            self.server_socket = socket.socket ( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
            
            self.server_address = ( "0.0.0.0", 0 )
    
    
    def serve_forever ( self, poll_interval = 0.5 ):
        if  bool ( self.proxy_args ) is False:
            self.socket.settimeout ( poll_interval )
            
            while not test_unittests_stop_event.is_set ():
                try:
                    self.handle_request ()
                except OSError:
                    pass
        else:
            d = {}
            
            while True:
                if ':' in (str)(self.proxy_args [ "proxy_host" ] ):
                    self.proxy_socket = socket.socket ( socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
                else:
                    self.proxy_socket = socket.socket ( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
                
                self.proxy_socket.setsockopt ( socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1 )
                
                self.proxy_socket.settimeout ( 10 )
                
                self.proxy_socket.connect ( ( self.proxy_args [ "proxy_host" ], self.proxy_args [ "proxy_port" ] ) )
                
                if "username" in self.proxy_args and "password" in self.proxy_args:
                    d [ "username" ] = self.proxy_args [ "username" ]
                    d [ "password" ] = self.proxy_args [ "password" ]
                
                server_socks5_client_send_greet ( self.proxy_socket, d )
                server_socks5_client_recv_choice ( self.proxy_socket, d )
                
                server_socks5_client_send_authorization_request ( self.proxy_socket, d )
                server_socks5_client_recv_authorization_response ( self.proxy_socket, d )
                
                d [ "cmd" ] = 2 # bind
                
                if "bind.ip.version" in d:
                    d [ "ip.version" ] = d [ "bind.ip.version" ]
                else:
                    d [ "ip.version" ] = 4
                    
                if "bind.ip" in d:
                    d [ "ip" ] = d [ "bind.ip" ]
                else:
                    d [ "ip" ] = "127.0.0.1"
                
                if "bind.port" in d:
                    d [ "port" ] = d [ "bind.port" ]
                else:
                    d [ "port" ] = 0
                
                # print ( d )
                
                server_socks5_client_send_connect_request ( self.proxy_socket, d )
                server_socks5_client_recv_connect_response ( self.proxy_socket, d )
                
                if "bind.ip" in d:
                    self.bind_host = d [ "bind.ip" ]
                
                if "bind.domain" in d:
                    self.bind_host = d [ "bind.domain" ]
                
                if "bind.port" in d:
                    self.bind_port = d [ "bind.port" ]
                
                print ( f"SOCKS5 Proxy listening on {self.bind_host}:{self.bind_port}" )
                
                self.proxy_socket.settimeout ( 18 )
                
                rlist, _, _ = select.select ( [ self.proxy_socket, ], [], [] )
                if self.proxy_socket in rlist:
                    l = {}
                    
                    server_socks5_client_recv_connect_response ( self.proxy_socket, l )
                    
                    address_0 = None
                    address_1 = None
                    
                    if "bind.ip" in l:
                        address_0 = l [ "bind.ip" ]
                    
                    if "bind.domain" in l:
                        address_0 = l [ "bind.domain" ]
                    
                    if "bind.port" in l:
                        address_1 = l [ "bind.port" ]
                    
                    client_address = ( address_0, address_1 )
                    
                    print ( f"Accepted connection from {address_0}:{address_1}" )
                    
                    self.RequestHandlerClass ( self.proxy_socket, client_address, self)
                    self.shutdown_request ( self.proxy_socket )

def server_socks5_client_send_greet ( s : socket.socket, d : dict ):
    # Client greeting   VER NAUTH       AUTH
    # Byte count          1     1   variable

    # VER
    #     SOCKS version (0x05)
    # NAUTH
    #     Number of authentication methods supported, uint8
    # AUTH
    #     Authentication methods, 1 byte per method supported
    #     The authentication methods supported are numbered as follows:

    #         0x00: No authentication
    #         0x01: GSSAPI (RFC 1961)
    #         0x02: Username/password (RFC 1929)
    #         0x03–0x7F: methods assigned by IANA[17]
    #             0x03: Challenge–Handshake Authentication Protocol
    #             0x04: Unassigned
    #             0x05: Challenge–Response Authentication Method
    #             0x06: Secure Sockets Layer
    #             0x07: NDS Authentication
    #             0x08: Multi-Authentication Framework
    #             0x09: JSON Parameter Block
    #             0x0A–0x7F: Unassigned
    #         0x80–0xFE: methods reserved for private use

    methods =  [ 0x00 ]
    
    if "username" in d and "password" in d:
        methods.append ( 0x02 )
        
    transmit = struct.pack ( "BB", 0x05, len ( methods ) )
    transmit += bytes ( methods )
    
    s.sendall ( transmit )


def server_socks5_client_recv_choice ( s : socket.socket, d : dict ):
    # Server choice
    #               VER CAUTH
    # Byte count      1     1

    # VER
    #     SOCKS version (0x05)
    # CAUTH
    #     chosen authentication method, or 0xFF if no acceptable methods were offered
    
    version, cauth = struct.unpack ( "!BB", s.recv ( 2 ) )
    
    if version != 0x5:
        raise SocksChainException ( "Unsupported socks version", version )
    
    if cauth == 0xff:
        raise AuthenticationChainException ( "No accepted AUTH type" )
    
    d [ "cauth" ] = cauth


def server_socks5_client_send_authorization_request ( s : socket.socket, d : dict ):
    #  Client authentication request, 0x02
    #               VER IDLEN       ID  PWLEN       PW
    # Byte count      1     1  (1–255)      1  (1–255)

    # VER
    #     0x01 for current version of username/password authentication
    # IDLEN, ID
    #     Username length, uint8; username as bytestring
    # PWLEN, PW
    #     Password length, uint8; password as bytestring
    
    if d [ "cauth" ] == 0x00:
        return
    
    if d [ "cauth" ] != 0x02:
        raise AuthenticationChainException ( "No accepted AUTH type" )
        
    if not "username" in d or not "password" in d:
        raise AuthenticationChainException ( "No AUTH without username and password not accepted" )
    
    transmit = b'\x01' # username/password authentication
    transmit += int.to_bytes ( len ( d [ "username" ] ) )
    transmit += str.encode ( d [ "username" ] )
    
    transmit += int.to_bytes ( len ( d [ "password" ] ) )
    transmit += str.encode ( d [ "password" ] )
    
    s.sendall ( transmit )


def server_socks5_client_recv_authorization_response ( s : socket.socket, d : dict ):
    # Server response, 0x02
    #               VER STATUS
    # Byte count      1      1

    # VER
    #     0x01 for current version of username/password authentication
    # STATUS
    #     0x00 success, otherwise failure, connection must be closed
    
    if d [ "cauth" ] == 0x00:
        return d
    
    version, status = struct.unpack ( "!BB", s.recv ( 2 ) )
    
    if version != 0x01:
        raise SocksChainException ( "Wrong socks username and password", version )
    
    if status != 0x00:
        raise AuthenticationChainException ( "Access denied", json.dumps ( d ) )


def server_socks5_client_send_connect_request ( s : socket.socket, d : dict ):
    # Client connection request
    #             VER CMD RSV  DSTADDR    DSTPORT
    # Byte Count    1   1   1 Variable          2
    
    # VER
    #     SOCKS version (0x05)
    # CMD
    #     command code:
    
    #         0x01: establish a TCP/IP stream connection
    #         0x02: establish a TCP/IP port binding
    #         0x03: associate a UDP port
    
    # RSV
    #     reserved, must be 0x00
    # DSTADDR
    #    SOCKS5 address  TYPE       ADDR
    #    Byte Count         1   variable
    
    #    TYPE
    #        type of the address. One of:
    
    #            0x01: IPv4 address
    #            0x03: Domain name
    #            0x04: IPv6 address
    # DSTPORT
    #     port number in a network byte order
    
    # print ( sys._getframe().f_lineno, d, file=sys.stderr )
    
    transmit = b'\x05'  # SOCKS version 5
    transmit += d [ "cmd" ].to_bytes ()
    transmit += b'\x00'  # Reserved
    
    if "ip.version" in d and d [ "ip.version" ] == 4:  # IPv4
        transmit += b'\x01'
        transmit += socket.inet_pton ( socket.AF_INET, d [ "ip" ] )
    elif "ip.version" in d and d [ "ip.version" ] == 6:  # IPv6
        transmit += b'\x04'
        transmit += socket.inet_pton ( socket.AF_INET6, d [ "ip" ] )
    elif "domain" in d:  # Domain name
        transmit += b'\x03'
        transmit += len ( d [ "domain" ] ).to_bytes ( 1, byteorder='big' )  # Length of domain
        transmit += d [ "domain" ].encode ( 'utf-8' )
    
    transmit += struct.pack('!H', d [ "port" ] )  # Port number
    
    s.sendall ( transmit )


def server_socks5_client_recv_connect_response ( s : socket.socket, d : dict ):
    # Response packet from server
    #               VER STATUS  RSV  BNDADDR    BNDPORT
    # Byte Count      1      1    1 variable          2
    
    # VER
    #     SOCKS version (0x05)
    # STATUS
    #     status code:
    
    #         0x00: request granted
    #         0x01: general failure
    #         0x02: connection not allowed by ruleset
    #         0x03: network unreachable
    #         0x04: host unreachable
    #         0x05: connection refused by destination host
    #         0x06: TTL expired
    #         0x07: command not supported / protocol error
    #         0x08: address type not supported
    
    # RSV
    #     reserved, must be 0x00
    # BNDADDR
    #    SOCKS5 address  TYPE       ADDR
    #    Byte Count         1   variable
    
    #    TYPE
    #        type of the address. One of:
    
    #            0x01: IPv4 address
    #            0x03: Domain name
    #            0x04: IPv6 address
    # BNDPORT
    #     server bound port number in a network byte order
    
    version, status, reserved, address_type = struct.unpack("!BBBB", s.recv(4))
    
    # Check for successful response
    
    if version != 0x05:
        raise SocksChainException ( "Unsupported socks version", version )
    
    if status != 0x00:
        raise SocksChainException ( "Socket chain error", status )
        
    # Parse the remaining response based on the address type
    if address_type == 0x01:  # IPv4
        d [ "bind.ip" ] = socket.inet_ntoa ( s.recv ( 4 ) )
        d [ "bind.ip.version" ] = 4
        d [ "bind.port" ] = struct.unpack ( "!H", s.recv ( 2 ) )[ 0 ]
    elif address_type == 0x03:  # Domain name
        domain_len = struct.unpack("!B", s.recv(1))[0]
        d [ "bind.domain" ] = s.recv ( domain_len ).decode ()
        d [ "bind.port" ] = struct.unpack ( "!H", s.recv ( 2 ) )[ 0 ]
    elif address_type == 0x04:  # IPv6
        d [ "bind.ip" ] = socket.inet_ntop ( socket.AF_INET6, s.recv ( 16 ) )
        d [ "bind.ip.version" ] = 6
        d [ "bind.port" ] = struct.unpack ( "!H", s.recv ( 2 ) )[ 0 ]
    else:
        raise Exception("Unknown address type")

Start http-proxy-server:
test_http_servers_listen_addresses = [
    { "proxy_host": '127.0.0.1', 'proxy_port': 1084 },
    { "proxy_host": '::1', 'proxy_port': 1076, "username": "username2", "password": "password5" },
]

for i in test_http_servers_listen_addresses:
    httpd = TestHTTPServerServer ( None, TestHTTPServerHandler, **i )
    
    server_thread = threading.Thread ( target=test_run_http_server, args = ( httpd, ) )
    server_thread.start ()

Tested with gost.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
